# yielded less than

Tags: meaning

What is the exact meaning of "yielded less than" in the following passage?

Furthermore, the Soviet Union's aspiration to establish diplomatic and economic pre-eminence in Iran yielded less than hegemonic results.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You broke the sentence down wrong. "less than hegemonic" is a modifier for "results". It is a slightly colorful way to say "non-hegemonic/anti-hegemonic results". Even understanding the construction, the sentence is hard to understand. I think it means that the USSR was unsuccessful in their attempts to exert influence in Iran.

Comment: @MikeGraham You are being kind to the author of this extract.  The word that springs to mind is ‘pretentious’ in a particularly British way.  It uses understatement ineptly.  All that was needed for the whole passage in question was the verb “failed”.